# How to create Extension Package in salesforce

Tags: deployment

My intend to create a base package with core features that will be used by my other packages. This will allow users to select only the packages that contain the features that they want, rather than giving them one large package with functionality that they will never use.

To create extension package, i read from salesforce help doc and i only did following step:

Installed my 'base managed package' in another dev org where i want to create extension package.
Could you please explain me that, what are the next steps. Let's say i have to give one new 'VF page' as an extra feature over my base package. Then how should i build extension package here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Step 1: Install the managed package (the "base" package) into a new developer edition.

Step 2: Give the new developer edition a new namespace, create the new managed package (the "extension" package), and upload that package.

Step 3: Done.

Some notes are worth pointing out here. The extension package will implicitly link itself not just to the base package, but also the *version* of the base package, on a per-upload basis. For example, if the base package is 1.25 and the extension package is 1.2, then the extension version 1.2 will be linked to base package 1.25, so you can't install 1.2 in an org with an older version (say, base version 1.24).

The linkage only occurs if you explicitly reference any element in the base package, such as a field, object, or class. Standard fields and objects do not count. The base package isn't ever allowed to reference the extension package explicitly, and so will need to use dynamic references and Apex Code. Keep this in mind when building your base package.

Be sure to use global interfaces and classes in the base package if the extension package needs to reference those items in the base package. You won't be able to easily remove these classes and methods later, so choose carefully. Once a version of the extension is linked to a version of the base package, you can't ask for a rollback of the base package to an earlier version than was linked, so also keep that in mind as well.

For all of the cautionary tales I present here, I'd like to mention that it is deceptively easy to create extension packages, even to the point where you could do so accidentally. For example, if you install a third-party managed package, and you accidentally reference a member of that package, it automatically gets linked as a dependency as soon as you upload that version. You can rollback the upload by contacting support, but not if you install it in any customer's org. At that point, the link is permanent.

I would strongly recommend avoid installing any managed package that you don't intend to link to, in order to avoid the accidental links. This also means you should never install the extension into the base package's host organization. Always use an ISV throw-away organization to test and demo how the two packages interact with each other, so that you can uninstall and rollback (or patch) if something goes wrong.

Comment: I have installed my base managed package into new dev org. and trying to create new extension package, but there is no any dependency component of base package, which i should add to my extension component. Could you please help me on, how should i add dependency of base package to extension package?

Comment: The dependency occurs only when you reference the other app through a link, such as a reference to a class, object, or field. You can't specify a dependency independently.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox for your response. sorry, i am completely new to salesforce, could you please give me idea for how to reference the app through link.

Comment: @HarishMache Any way you want. Call a method, query a field, do anything that results in a hard reference to the base package.

Comment: @sfdcfox, quick idea if we can use this in normal dev orgs and not with ISV orgs? Thanks

Comment: @KaushikRay Any developer org (ISV or standard) can make managed packages that can be extensions, but other types of orgs, like ISV demo or trial orgs, cannot.

Comment: thanks @sfdcfox , the reason for this question was , as we can create patch from ISV only and not from normal dev orgs, so was wondering same about extentions

Comment: @sfdcfox two questions... can an extension package linked to a base package (say 1.25) be installed by a customer with a subsequent base package version (say 1.26)? Then, can we update the base package without updating every time the extension package?Just to understand how this version linking works and how to manage that, because I think we'll update the base package more frequently then the extension package, and don't want our customers to update both packages every time... Thanks

Comment: @ctrl-z Yes, any subsequent version of the base package is acceptable for the extension package that depends on it. The only stipulation is that the extension package will be linked to whatever version is installed in the extension packaging org when the upload happens, so you should avoid updating the extension package's installed version until you need a new feature to ensure that the maximum number of subscribers can install it without upgrading the base package.

Answer (score 0):

Now you need to create a new package and add your extension components. Salesforce automatically include the related components.

Upload the new package that contains the extension components